# AS3 - Shooting arrows / targeting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am creating a game where fairies cross the screen (bottom to top). There is a laser at the bottom of the screen that goes from right to left. I want to shoot the laser, and have the laser bullets to go from bottom to top. The code that I have has it going from top to bottom. I have tried to reverse the direction by changing out the + = 10 to - = 10... This did get the bullets in the right direction, however, it started it towards the top of my screen.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, targeting)

function targeting(e:MouseEvent):void{
var newArrow:blackArrow = new blackArrow();
addChild(newArrow);
newArrow.y = 50; 
newArrow.x = shooterMC.x;
newArrow.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shoot);
}
function shoot(e:Event):void {
var arrowMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
arrowMC.y += 10;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help that you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this line to your desired position you want to start the laser animation from:

```
newArrow.y = 50;
```

The coordinate system starts in the upper left corner. So the lower right corner is `window width | window height`.

Comment: You are brilliant! Thank you so much. It is always the simplest things that are over looked.

Comment: @user2250171: You're welcome. It would be great if you accept the answer as the correct one if the timer of 15 minutes is finished :)